# How to refetch an apollo vuejs after an external oauth2 completion

Tags: vue.js, oauth-2.0, vue-apollo

I have a vuejs/apollo grapqhl Single page app. At one point there is an option to connect it another service (in this case vimeo). The flow is

1. click to start - this goes to the graphql server and collects a
   redirect link to the vimeo oauth2 server with some state attached,
   then does the redirect
2. the consent dialog happens on the vimeo oauth2 server, which
   redirects to a route on the graphql server - this updates the back
   end database with the vimeo user profile, and then returns to the
   main front end app where it left off.
3. at this point I need to refetch the data updated at step 2, but of course I can't detect when this is complete.

Any suggestions as to how to co-erce the front end to refetch when step 3 is complete ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I figured out how to do this. Just check for the tab coming back into focus using ifvisible, and force a refetch when it does.

```
  mounted () {
    const that = this
    ifvisible.on('focus', () => that.$apollo.queries.UserProfile.refetch())
  }
```